# How to calculate $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{x(x-\pi)\cot(x)dx}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I know how to calculate $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{x\cot(x)dx}$

But when it adds $(x-\pi)$, I don't know how to do.

Comment: Make sure you put the $dx$ in otherwise the integral doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry. I edited it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Integration by parts tells that

$$
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x(x-\pi)\cot x \, dx
= \underbrace{\left[ x(x-\pi) \log\sin x \right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}}_{=0} - \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (2x-\pi) \log\sin x \, dx.
$$

Now notice that

$$ -\log\sin x = -\log\left| \frac{1 - e^{2ix}}{2}\right| = \log 2 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (2nx)}{n} $$

So we have

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x(x-\pi)\cot x \, dx
&= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (2x-\pi) \left( \log 2 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (2nx)}{n} \right) \, dx \\
&= -\frac{\pi^2}{4}\log 2 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n - 1}{2n^3} \\
&= -\frac{\pi^2}{4}\log 2 - \frac{7}{8}\zeta(3).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x\pars{x - \pi}\cot\pars{x}\,\dd x}}
\stackrel{\mrm{IBP}}{=}
-\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\pars{2x - \pi}\ln\pars{\sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] \stackrel{x\ \mapsto\ \pi/2 - x}{=}&\
2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x\ln\pars{\cos\pars{x}}\,\dd x =
\left.2\,\Re\int_{x\ =\ 0}^{x\ =\ \pi/2}
\bracks{-\ic\ln\pars{z}}\ln\pars{1 + z^{2} \over 2z}\,{\dd z \over \ic z}
\,\right\vert_{\ z\ =\ \exp\pars{\ic x}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\left. -2\,\Re\int_{x\ =\ 0}^{x\ =\ \pi/2}
\ln\pars{z}\ln\pars{1 + z^{2} \over 2z}\,{\dd z \over z}
\,\right\vert_{\ z\ =\ \exp\pars{\ic x}}
\\[1cm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{\large +}}{\sim}&\
2\,\Re\int_{1}^{\epsilon}
\bracks{\ln\pars{y} + {\pi \over 2}\,\ic}
\bracks{\ln\pars{1 - y^{2} \over 2y} - {\pi \over 2}\,\ic}
\,{\ic\,\dd y \over \ic y}
\\[2mm] &\
+ 2\,\Re\int_{\pi/2}^{0}\bracks{\ln\pars{\epsilon} + \ic\theta}
\bracks{-\ln\pars{2\epsilon} - \ic\theta}\,{\epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}\ic\,\dd\theta \over \epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}} +
2\,\Re\int_{\epsilon}^{1}
\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 + x^{2} \over 2x}\,{\dd x \over x}
\\[1cm] =&\
-2\int_{\epsilon}^{1}
\bracks{\ln\pars{y}\ln\pars{1 - y^{2} \over 2y} + {\pi^{2} \over 4}}
\,{\dd y \over y} -
2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\bracks{\ln\pars{2} + 2\ln\pars{\epsilon}}\theta\,\dd\theta
\\[2mm] &\
+ 2\int_{\epsilon}^{1}
\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 + x^{2} \over 2x}\,{\dd x \over x}
\\[1cm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{\large +}}{\sim}&\
-2\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{y}\ln\pars{1 - y^{2}} \over y}\,\dd y -
2\int_{\epsilon}^{1}{-\ln\pars{y}\ln\pars{2y} + \pi^{2}/4 \over y}\,\dd y -
\bracks{\ln\pars{2} + 2\ln\pars{\epsilon}}\,{\pi^{2} \over 4}
\\[2mm] &\
2\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 + x^{2}} \over x}\,\dd x -
2\int_{\epsilon}^{1}{\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{2x} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[1cm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\to}&\
-\,{\pi^{2} \over 4}\,\ln\pars{2} -
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{\xi}\ln\pars{1 - \xi} \over \xi}\,\dd\xi +
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{\xi}\ln\pars{1 + \xi} \over \xi}\,\dd\xi
\\[1cm] = &\
-\,{\pi^{2} \over 4}\,\ln\pars{2} -
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{\xi}\ln\pars{1 - \xi} \over \xi}\,\dd\xi +
\left[{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{\xi}\ln\pars{1 - \xi^{2}} \over \xi}\,\dd\xi\right.
\\[2mm] &\
\left. - {1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{\xi}\ln\pars{1 - \xi} \over \xi}\,\dd\xi\right]
\\[1cm] = &\
-\,{\pi^{2} \over 4}\,\ln\pars{2} -
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{\xi}\ln\pars{1 - \xi} \over \xi}\,\dd\xi +
\left[{1 \over 8}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{\xi}\ln\pars{1 - \xi} \over \xi}\,\dd\xi\right.
\\[2mm] &\
\left. - {1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{\xi}\ln\pars{1 - \xi} \over \xi}\,\dd\xi\right]
\\[1cm] = &\
-\,{\pi^{2} \over 4}\,\ln\pars{2} -
{7 \over 8}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{\xi}\ln\pars{1 - \xi} \over \xi}\,\dd\xi =
-\,{\pi^{2} \over 4}\,\ln\pars{2} +
{7 \over 8}\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{\xi}\,\mrm{Li}_{2}'\pars{\xi}\,\dd\xi
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{\pi^{2} \over 4}\,\ln\pars{2} -
{7 \over 8}\int_{0}^{1}\overbrace{\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{\xi} \over \xi}
^{\ds{\mrm{Li}_{3}'\pars{\xi}}}\,\dd\xi =
-\,{\pi^{2} \over 4}\,\ln\pars{2} - {7 \over 8}\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{1}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{-\,{\pi^{2} \over 4}\,\ln\pars{2} - {7 \over 8}\,\zeta\pars{3}}
\approx -2.7621
\end{align}